# Using matlabs regress like polyfit

Tags: matlab

I have:

```
x = [1970:1:2000]
y = [data]

size(x) = [30,1]
size(y) = [30,1]
```

I want:

```
% Yl = kx + m, where
[k,m] = polyfit(x,y,1)
```

For some reason i have to use "regress" for this.

Using k = regress(x,y) gives some totally random value that i have no idea where it comes from. How do it?

Comment: If you look at the documentation for [`regress`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/regress.html), it says that the proper form is `k = regress(y,X)`. Are you sure you're using the proper form? Also, how do you know its a totally random value?

Answer (score 3):

The number of outputs you get in "k" is dependant on the size of input X, so you will not get both `m` and `k` just by putting in your x and y straight.  From the docs:

> b = regress(y,X) returns a p-by-1 vector b of coefficient estimates for a multilinear regression of the responses in y on the predictors in X. X is an n-by-p matrix of p predictors at each of n observations. y is an n-by-1 vector of observed responses.

It is not exactly stated, but the example in the help docs using the `carsmall` inbuilt dataset shows you how to set this up. For your case, you'd want:

```
X = [ones(size(x)) x]; % make sure this is 30 x 2
b = regress(y,X);  % y should be 30 x 1, b should be 2 x 1
```

`b(1)` should then be your `m`, and `b(2)` your `k`.

`regress` can also provide additional outputs, such as confidence intervals, residuals, statistics such as r-squared, etc.  The input remains the same, you'd just change the outputs:

```
[b,bint,r,rint,stats] = regress(y,X);
```